# python program seems to run another (local) program automatically without being requested to

Tags: python, base64, shared-libraries

(if you're opposed to mixing programming and humor skip directly to the question in the last paragraph)

we've just encountered a near x-files experience when a python program started printing its output in base64 encoding, without being asked to. Actually, it was not the output but the content of the stdin it got. In fact, the program tried to read the stdin but got an empty string, yet the stdin was mysteriously read by something and passed to the stdout base64-encoded.

When we reached this state of complete bewilderment, someone noticed that the directory contains another program named `base64.py`. When we deleted it the behavior went back to normal.

I hear that this is an expected behavior that may be related to some `textwrap` python feature. I will spare you what I think of such a "feature", but I can't find any reference to it and I am curious. Not to the textwrap that is but to the phenomena of using programs found in the neighborhood without being asked.

So if someone cares to explain and/or provide some references I'd be grateful.

(python 2.6 on RHEL 5.7)

**EDIT**:
I can't show the code as the real code is proprietary, and an example I tried to put up didn't show this behavior.
The question is really this:

**Under what circumstances a python program may run another program named `base64.py` found in the same directory and pass its standard input to it?**

**EDIT2:**
edited the subject to reflect the solution better
`textwrap` above is just a "red herring"

Comment: @user2799617: I can't publish the real code as it is a part of a proprietary product, and it also would be too overwhelming with details not related to the phenomena I'm asking for. I did try to fudge some mini-example but guess what? - it didn't happen there. I am no rookie you know. But enjoy the power, why not

Comment: response to the on-hold: as I say in the edit and in comment, I can't post the real code and I could not make an example to show the problem. I believe that the problem is described specifically, considering its vagueness.

Answer (score 3):

`base64` is the name of [a standard library module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html). You mention there was another program named `base64.py`. That program got executed when some part of your program tried to import the standard module (or another module that in turn depends on `base64`).

See also [section 6.1.2. The Module Search Path in the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

> The directory containing the script being run is placed at the beginning of the search path, ahead of the standard library path. This means that scripts in that directory will be loaded instead of modules of the same name in the library directory.

Comment: excellent! I've just got to the same conclusion myself. In addition, our base64 program didn't conform to the common practice, namely didn't check whether it runs as a standalone program or being loaded as a module - just read the input and encoded it